# Newton's second law in non inertial frames: why am I getting $r_x = 0$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, inertial-frames

Consider the following system:

[image]

and the following frame:

> A rotating frame $x^{\prime} y^{\prime} z^{\prime}$ whose origin coincides with the inertial frame $x y z$ and the $z^{\prime}$ and $z$ directions are the same such that the ring remains in the $x^{\prime} z^{\prime}$ plane during the motion of the system.

Let assume that the ring is rotating with a constant angular velocity $\omega$. We now wish to find the equation of motion in the above reference frame.

---

As the real forces we have 
$$\vec F_{net} = (-mg)z' + (N\sin(\theta))z' + (N\cos(\theta))x' + (-kR\theta \cos(\theta))x' + (kR\theta \sin(\theta))z'.$$

Now, since our frame rotates with the ring we have: $$(\vec r)_y =  0\quad, \quad D(\vec r)_y = 0\quad \text{and} \quad D^2 (\vec r)_y = 0.$$ So, if we write Newton's second law in this non inertial frame, we get

$$m  \ddot{\vec r} = \vec F_{net} - 2m (\vec \omega) \times (\vec r) + \omega\times \omega \times \vec r,$$
and since $\vec \omega = w z'$, we have

$$m \ddot{\vec r} = \vec F_{net} + (-2m \dot r_x w )y' + (r_x w^2)x'.$$

**However**, since $(\ddot{\vec r})_y = 0 $ and $(\vec F_{net})_y = 0$, we must have $r_x = \text{constant}$, but **this does not make sense.**

---

I thought the error was due to the assumption that the velocity and the acceleration in the $y$ direction is zero, but if I don't assume that, then I'm basically not including the information that the frame is rotating with the ring into the problem. So, I'm confused about where the problem is in this analysis.

Comment: Sorry, Could you explain in detail why x-coordinate is zero according to your computations?

Comment: @amejmar Because in both sides of the equation there is only one term whose $y$ component is nonzero, that is $-2m \dot r_x w$, so this terms should be equal to zero.

Comment: But it implies that rx has to be constant, not necessarily zero

Comment: @amejmar You are right, but that still makes no sense because the particle is still not moving

Comment: “As the real forces we have” what is N and what is k, I see a spring in your figure, how you calculate this force?

Comment: @Eli The effect of those forces does not change under change of reference frame, so that is we are saying them "real" forces, thought experimentally how do you measure them, or even differentiate one from the other is another issue. Note that we don't know the value of $N$ in this analysis, but we don't have to; we can still get the EoF without knowing the value of $N$.

Comment: your EOM are described in rotating system  so $\ddot{y}_B$ is not zero. $y_S$ and $\ddot{y}_S$ in space coordinate system are zero.

Comment: @Eli Not really. In the space frame, the ring is rotating, so $y_s, \dot y_s, \ddot_y$ are not zero. In the rotating frame, since the ring is always in $x-z$ plane, the mass cannot move to $y$ axis, so its velocity and acceleration in that direction should also be zero for all times.